# Test the convergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, summation

Test the convergence of $\left (a_{n} \right)$ if 
$$a_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left( \sqrt[\left \lfloor \frac{m}{4} \right \rfloor]{k^2+1}  -\sqrt[\left \lfloor \frac{m}{4} \right \rfloor]{k^2-1} \right), \quad m\in \mathbb{N}$$

I need a hint as to what to do with $\lfloor \frac{m}{4} \rfloor$ since I have no idea how to do any manipulations with these roots.

Comment: That's bizarre.  Since $m$ can apparently be any natural number, the floor function allows the radix degree (?) to be any non-negative integer.  It's undefined for $0$, as far as I know, and it's clearly divergent when it's $1$ (since that's just the identity function).

Comment: Yeah it looks bizarre to me also. Moreover, after testing the convergence of $a_{n}$ the problem continues demanding to test the convergence of sum of arcsin and arccot of the two elements in brackets above, also. Do you have any idea on what condition for $m$ this would make more sense?

Comment: One way to arrive at an intuition for the answer is to approximate $\sqrt[r]{u+1}-\sqrt[r]{u-1}$ with $2\frac{d}{du} u^{1/r} = \frac{2}{ru^{(r-1)/r}}$, which evaluates in the current problem to $\frac{2}{rk^{2(r-1)/r}}$.  For what values of $r$ will such a series converge?  But then you still have to demonstrate the convergence for various $r$ more rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

Name $\alpha=\left \lfloor \frac{m}{4} \right \rfloor$ and $b_k=\sqrt[\alpha]{k^2+1}  -\sqrt[\alpha]{k^2-1}$. You have $$b_k=k^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\left(\sqrt[\alpha]{1+\frac{1}{k^2}}  -\sqrt[\alpha]{1-\frac{1}{k^2}}\right)=k^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}\left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{1}{k^2}  -(1-\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{1}{k^2}) + o\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\right)=\frac{2k^{\frac{2}{\alpha}-2}}{\alpha}+o \left( k^{\frac{2}{\alpha}-2}\right)$$ as $k \to \infty$.

From there, you have to study a series of the type $\sum k^\beta$, which convergence depends on the value of $\beta=\frac{2}{\alpha}-2$.